# how do we fill some fields of the looped row with what we have chooses in the onchange in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, date

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXTtL.png)
Whenever choose the date and rate fields, this data should filled with looped fields which I have marked
The admin no need to fill the date and rate fields for every row. Once its chooses it will be automatically filled with all row.

// my html code

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group" style="padding-right:10px; width:100%;">
      <input type="month" name="pickmonth" id="pickmonth"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('Y-m'); ?>">
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group" style="padding-right:10px; width:100%;">
         <select class="custom-select " name="empDesignation" id="empDesignation">
                <option selected>Choose Rate</option>
                <?php foreach($rates as $rate){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rate['rate_amount']; ?>"><?php echo $rate['rate_amount']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>

          </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

// ajax looped data. 
id for rate is #rate, 
id for date is #date, 
You can see below this fields.

```
 success: function(data) {                   
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        html += '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].emp_name +
                            '<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="emp_id"  name="emp_id"  required value="' +
                            data[i].emp_id + '"> </td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].cat_name +
                            '<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="cat_id"  name="cat_id" required value="' +
                            data[i].cat_id + '"></td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].emp_account_number + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="attendance"  name="attendance" placeholder="Attendance" required>' +
                            '</td>' +
                              '<td>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="rate"  name="rate" placeholder="Rate" required>' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cdf"  name="cdf" placeholder="CDF" required>' +
                            '</td>' +
                               '<td>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lic"  name="lic" placeholder="LIC" required>' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + '<div id="loanBalance" style="display:none;color:#02c0ce; max-width: 100%; padding: .469rem .469rem; font-size: 14px;  ">Balance Amount: <span id="balance"></span></div>' +

                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="loan"  name="loan" placeholder="Loan" required>' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<input style="display:block;"  class="form-control" id="date" autocomplete="off" name="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy Choose Date" >' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-edit" id="btnSave">Submit</button>' +
                            '</td>' +

                            '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('#salaryData').html(html);

                    // $('#salaryData').html(data);
                },
```

I have tried with some code but its changing only first field .

```
var date_input = document.getElementById('pickmonth');
    date_input.valueAsDate = new Date();

    date_input.onchange = function(){
       let choosenDate = this.value;
       $('#date').attr('value',choosenDate);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

change

```
class="form-control" id="date"
```

to

```
class="form-control date"

// then
date_input.onchange = function(){
  let choosenDate = this.value;
  $('.date').attr('value',choosenDate);

}
```